# perl threading problem

Tags: perl, multithreading

I'm writing a multithreaded website uptime checker in perl, and here is the basic code so far (includes only threading part):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent; 
use Getopt::Std; 
use threads; 
use threads::shared; 

my $maxthreads :shared = 50;
my $threads :shared = 0;

print "Website Uptime Checker\n";
my $infilename = $ARGV[0];
chomp($infilename);
open(INFILE, $infilename);
my $outfilename = $ARGV[1];
chomp($outfilename);
open(OUTFILE, ">" . $outfilename);
OUTFILE->autoflush(1);
while ($site = <INFILE>)
{
    chomp($site);
    while (1)
    {
        if ($threads < $maxthreads)
        {
            $threads++;
            my $thr = threads->create(\&check_site, $site);
            $thr->detach();
            last;
        }
        else
        {
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
while ($threads > 0)
{
    sleep(1);
}

sub check_site
{
    $server = $_[0];
    print "$server\n";
    $threads--;
}
```

It gives an error after a while:

> Can't call method "detach" on an undefined value at C:\perl\webchecker.pl line 28,  line 245.

What causes this error? I know it is at detach, but what am I doing wrong in my code? Windows shows lots of free memory, so it should not be the computer running out of memory, this error occurs even if I set $maxthreads as low as 10 or possibly even lower.

Comment: sorry but this site convers #!/usr/bin/perl to !/usr/bin/perl (deletes first character) please ignore that

Comment: Unless this is a threading experiment, consider Parallel::ForkManager or Thread::Queue.

Answer (score 1):

The specific issue is that `thread->create` is failing to create a thread and so it is returning `undef`.  You should check the value of `thr` before calling `detach` if you want your code to be more robust.

Comment: ok thanks that seems to work, I added check if undef and if so sleep(1) and try again until it works and it is going through the list just fine now

Comment: sorry, an error did occur later on:

panic: attempt to copy freed scalar 32c0bb4 to 23b080c at C:\perl\webchecker.pl line 24, <INFILE> line 15863.
Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x32c0bb4, Perl interpreter: 0x3354584.

What caused this error?

Comment: Alice Wozownik, it's probably better to [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this different problem. Paste your code again and also name the version of Perl and of the used `threads` modules.

Comment: Yes, that's a different problem now.